# Multiple where clause in sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a simple `sessions` table which looks like this:

```
   sid  watchtime
    1   01:07:00
    2   01:07:00
    3   01:34:00
    4   01:36:00
    5   01:36:00
    6   01:59:00
    7   01:59:00
    8   00:00:00
    9   00:00:00
    10  03:42:00
    11  00:16:00
    12  00:49:00
    13  00:55:00
    14  00:00:00
    15  00:05:00
    16  00:05:00
```

Now, I want to display count for watchtime `>=5` and watchtime `<5`. I tried the following solution:

```
SELECT count(watchtime) as lessthan_five FROM sessions 
WHERE watchtime <=5 
AND count(watchtime) as morethan_five 
         from sessions WHERE watchtime >5";
```

I am getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as morethanfive from sessions where WHERE watchtime >=5"' at line 1

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by watchtime >= 5? >= 5 minutes (i.e. 00:05:00)?

Comment: @Nick yes , exactly

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the result you want, making use of MySQL treating boolean values as 1 or 0 in a numeric context:

```
SELECT SUM(watchtime <= '00:05:00') AS lessthan_five,
       SUM(watchtime >  '00:05:00') AS morethan_five
FROM sessions
```

Output:

```
lessthan_five   morethan_five
5               11
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLc1RtwX6nFHq2o9f3fznV/0)

Comment: I will accept later when stack will allow me to do so :P

Answer (score 1):

If you want rows with value more than five minutes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE watchtime >= '00:05:00'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE watchtime < '00:05:00'
```

If you want number of rows with minutes past the hour:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE MINUTE(watchtime) >= 5
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE MINUTE(watchtime) < 5
```

Also, this will give you the count for all watchtime, where the count <> 5:

```
SELECT watchtime, COUNT(*) as Num
FROM sessions 
GROUP BY watchtime
HAVING COUNT(*) <> 5
```

You can edit the having-clause as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
   SELECT watchtime, count(watchtime) as lessthan_five FROM sessions 
   WHERE watchtime <=5 
   AND watchtime in ( select watchtime as morethan_five 
     from sessions group by `category_id` having `watchtime` >5);
```

Comment: I get the following error :  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by watchtime having count(watchtime) >5)"' at line 4 `

Comment: Please find this link for more help on Group by and Having in mysql https://www.guru99.com/group-by.html